Curved list effect animation using Transform.translate?
I'm working on a Flutter animation where I need to move an list of item in a curved manner. I have managed to create the shifting animation and give the effect of the item moving in a curved manner, but it's not perfect. Currently, the item shifts in a straight form from point A to point B, rather than a curved. I need improvement to make the movement appear as a perfect curve. I have attached the code and a video sample for reference.
Video link : https://jmp.sh/s/w03nb6F43UfUzG4gfdqw
class CurvedAn extends StatefulWidget {
 const CurvedAn({super.key});


 @override
 State<CurvedAn> createState() => _CurvedAnState();
}


class _CurvedAnState extends State<CurvedAn>
   with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
 late AnimationController _controller;
 late Animation<double> _animation;


 List<Widget> _items = [
   Icon(Icons.account_circle),
   Icon(Icons.account_box_sharp),
   Icon(Icons.access_time),
   Icon(Icons.ac_unit_sharp),
   Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet_sharp),
 ];


 bool _animating = false;


 @override
 void initState() {
   // Step 2: Initialize the AnimationController
   _controller = AnimationController(
     duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
     vsync: this,
   );


   // Step 3: Set up the scale animation
   _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
     CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeInOut),
   );


   _controller.addStatusListener(_listener);


   super.initState();
 }


 @override
 void dispose() {
   _controller.dispose();
   super.dispose();
 }


 void _listener(AnimationStatus status) {
   _animating = status.isAnimating;
   setState(() {});
 }


 void _moveRight() {
   _controller.reset();
   _controller.forward();
 }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Column(
     children: [
       FloatingActionButton(
         onPressed: () {
           _moveRight();
         },
         child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
       ),
       SizedBox(height: 8.0),
       ClipPath(
         clipper: CurveClipper(),
         child: Container(
           width: 360.0,
           height: 80.0,
           color: Colors.red,
           child: Stack(
             children: [
               for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; i++)
                 AnimatedBuilder(
                   animation: _animation,
                   builder: (context, child) {
                     double x = 0;
                     double y = 0;


                     if (i == 0) {
                       if (_animating) {




                         x = 144 + (72 * _animation.value);
                         y = -20 + (12 * _animation.value);
                       } else {
                         x = 72 * 2;
                         y = -20;
                       }
                     } else if (i == 1) {
                       if (_animating) {
                         x = 216 + (72 * _animation.value);
                         y = -8 + (18 * _animation.value);
                       } else {
                         x = 72 * 3;
                         y = -8;
                       }
                     } else if (i == 2) {
                       if (_animating) {
                         x = 288 + (72 * _animation.value);
                         y = 10 + (20 * _animation.value);
                       } else {
                         x = 72 * 4;
                         y = 10;
                       }
                     } else if (i == 4) {
                       if (_animating) {
                         x = 72 + (72 * _animation.value);
                         y = -8 - (12 * _animation.value);
                       } else {
                         x = 72 * 1;
                         y = -8;
                       }
                     } else if (i == 3) {
                       if (_animating) {
                         x = 72 * _animation.value;
                         y = 10 - (20 * _animation.value);
                       } else {
                         x = 0;
                         y = 10;
                       }
                     }


                     return Transform.translate(
                       offset: Offset(x, y),
                       child: Container(
                         height: 72,
                         width: 72,
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                           border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent),
                         ),
                         child: _items[i],
                       ),
                     );
                   },
                 ),
               if (_animating)
                 AnimatedBuilder(
                   animation: _animation,
                   builder: (context, child) {
                     double x = 0;
                     double y = 0;


                     // x = -72 + (144 * _animation.value);
                     // y = 72 + (-62 * _animation.value);


                     x = -60 + (60 * _animation.value);
                     y = 30 + (-20 * _animation.value);


                     return Transform.translate(
                       offset: Offset(x, y),
                       child: Container(
                         height: 72,
                         width: 72,
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                           border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent),
                         ),
                         child: _items[0],
                       ),
                     );
                   },
                 ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ],
   );
 }
}


so instead of x = -60 + (60 * _animation.value); y = 30 + (-20 * _animation.value); you should use something like x = xc + r * cos(a); y = yc + r * sin(a) - more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Parametric_form

@pskink placing items in a circular pattern using this formula will fit within a container with a height of 80?

sorry, I cannot find any container with a height == 80

@pskink Apologies for the confusion earlier. I’ve updated the code, the main container where the items will be placed.

well, it will work but you have to know the center of the red arc (the one that is defined by your CurveClipper)

I'm able to achieve the curve effect, thanks to @pskink suggestion. The only thing I did differently was using quadratic Bezier curve formula instead of using a circle formula.
enum ShiftMode {
 forward,
 backward,
}


class BezierCurveItems extends StatefulWidget {
 const BezierCurveItems({super.key});


 @override
 State<BezierCurveItems> createState() => _BezierCurveItemsState();
}


class _BezierCurveItemsState extends State<BezierCurveItems>
   with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
 late double _width;
 late double _height;
 late int _visibleItemCount;
 ShiftMode? _shiftMode;
 late double _itemWidth;


 late AnimationController _controller;
 late Animation<double> _animation;
 late Tween<double> _tween;


 List<Widget> _items = [
   Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
   Icon(Icons.access_time),
   Icon(Icons.account_box_sharp),
   Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
   Icon(Icons.account_tree),
 ];


 @override
 void initState() {
   _width = 360.0;
   _height = 80.0;
   _visibleItemCount = 5;
   _itemWidth = _width / _visibleItemCount;


   _controller = AnimationController(
     vsync: this,
     duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
   );


   _tween = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0);


   _animation = _tween.animate(
     CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeInOut),
   );


   super.initState();
 }


 _shiftRightForward() {
   _shiftMode = ShiftMode.forward;
   _controller.reset();
   _controller.forward();
 }


 _shiftLeftForward() {
   _shiftMode = ShiftMode.backward;
   _controller.reset();
   _controller.forward();
 }


 double _getX(int i, double av) {
   // Calculate x position for the item
   double xPos = (i * (_width / (_visibleItemCount)));


   if (_shiftMode == ShiftMode.forward) {
     double xPosNext = ((i + 1) * (_width / (_visibleItemCount)));
     double interpolateX = lerpDouble(xPos, xPosNext, av)!;
     return interpolateX;
   } else if (_shiftMode == ShiftMode.backward) {
     double xPosPrev = ((i - 1) * (_width / (_visibleItemCount)));
     double interpolateX = lerpDouble(xPos, xPosPrev, av)!;
     return interpolateX;
   } else {
     return xPos;
   }
 }


 double _getY(int i, double av) {
   double yPos = _calculateBezierY(i);


   if (_shiftMode == ShiftMode.forward) {
     double yPosNext = _calculateBezierY(i + 1);
     return lerpDouble(yPos, yPosNext, av)!;
   } else if (_shiftMode == ShiftMode.backward) {
     double yPosPrev = _calculateBezierY(i - 1);
     return lerpDouble(yPos, yPosPrev, av)!;
   } else {
     return yPos;
   }
 }


 double _calculateBezierY(int i) {
   // Bezier curve control points
   Offset p0 = Offset(0, _height / 2);
   Offset p1 = Offset(_width / 2, 0); // Control point
   Offset p2 = Offset(_width, _height / 2);


   double t = i / (_visibleItemCount - 1);


   return (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p0.dy + 2 * (1 - t) * t * p1.dy + t * t * p2.dy;
 }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     floatingActionButton: Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: [
         FloatingActionButton(
           onPressed: () => _shiftLeftForward(),
           child: Icon(Icons.navigate_before),
         ),
         FloatingActionButton(
           onPressed: () async {
             _shiftRightForward();
             await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
             _shiftRightForward();
           },
           child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
         )
       ],
     ),
     appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Bezier Curve Items")),
     body: Container(
       width: 360.0,
       height: 80.0,
       color: Colors.grey.shade400,
       child: AnimatedBuilder(
         animation: _animation,
         builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
           return Stack(
             children: [
               for (int i = 0; i < _visibleItemCount; i++)
                 Transform.translate(
                   offset: Offset(
                     _getX(i, _animation.value),
                     _getY(i, _animation.value),
                   ),
                   child: Container(
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       border: Border.all(color: Colors.black54),
                     ),
                     alignment: Alignment.center,
                     width: _itemWidth,
                     child: _items[i],
                   ),
                 ),
               if (_shiftMode == ShiftMode.forward)
                 Transform.translate(
                   offset: Offset(
                     _getX(-1, _animation.value),
                     _getY(-1, _animation.value),
                   ),
                   child: Container(
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       border: Border.all(color: Colors.black54),
                     ),
                     alignment: Alignment.center,
                     width: _itemWidth,
                     child: _items[0],
                   ),
                 ),
               if (_shiftMode == ShiftMode.backward)
                 Transform.translate(
                   offset: Offset(
                     _getX(_visibleItemCount, _animation.value),
                     _getY(_visibleItemCount, _animation.value),
                   ),
                   child: Container(
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       border: Border.all(color: Colors.black54),
                     ),
                     alignment: Alignment.center,
                     width: _itemWidth,
                     child: _items[0],
                   ),
                 ),
             ],
           );
         },
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}


